# Looking for someone to check my work on some more convergence and divergence problems.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm supposed to find whether each series is convergent or divergent and then explain why.

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n} + 1} {n^2 + ln(n)}$
2. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{5n+1}$

---

So for #1, I realize that I can use the **limit comparison test**.

We have $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$ which leaves us with something that looks like a p-series $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$. Since $\frac{3}{2}$ is greater than 1, our series converges.

Now, I need to actually apply the limit comparison test.

$ \lim_{n->\infty} \frac{ \frac{\sqrt{n} +1}{n^2 + ln(n)}} { \frac{1}{ n^{\frac{3}{2}}} }$

After multiplying through, that leaves me with

$ \frac{n^2 + n^{\frac{3}{2}}} {n^2 + ln(n)} $

I can either do L'Hospital's rules on it, or since we now have two n's with the same power, we can take the ratio and know that is the limit. So it goes to 1.

Since 1 > 0. We can assume the original series also converges.

*I sure hope I did that right, otherwise that was a lot of work for nothing!*

---

For #2, it looks like we already have n with the same power. Are we simply able to say that it converges to $\frac{1}{5}$ due to this? Or am I supposed to show this with some test?

Comment: For the first problem, I would suggest noting that the top is $\le 2\sqrt{n}$, and the bottom is $\ge n^2$, so our $n$-th term is $\le \frac{2}{n^{3/2}}$. But $\sum \frac{2}{n^{3/2}}$ converges. For the second, the limit of the $n$-th term is $\frac{1}{5}$, which you can show by dividing top and bottom by $n$. Or you can show that the $n$-th term is $\gt \frac{1}{10}$ for large enough $n$. Either way, you can see that the $n$-th term does not approach $0$, so the series diverges.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm slightly confused as to why you are noting the top and bottom comparisons. Where did they come from? I'm still learning :)

Comment: We want to show that the $n$-th term is "small," goes to $0$ "fast enough." The intuition is that it kind of behaves like $1/n^{3/2}$. If we get rid of the $\log n$ at the bottom, we make the thing bigger, but still going down fast enough. If we replace $\sqrt{n}+1$ on top by $2\sqrt{n}$, we have made the thing bigger, but still going down fast enough. Now use the magic word Comparison Test.

Comment: Oh! I get it :) Thank you for explaining the reasoning behind picking those numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, note:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n} + 1} {n^2 + \ln(n)} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n} + 1} {n^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}} {n^2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1} {n^2}$$

The last two series clearly converge using your $p$-test with $p > 1$.

---

**Edit:** For the second problem, observe the term limit is $1/5$, perhaps by dividing numerator and denominator by $n$ and letting $n \rightarrow \infty$. Since $1/5 \neq 0$, the series diverges.

Comment: Yes, I can use any method to prove convergence or divergence. Am I not allowed to do it the way I did? Or is it just that the way you did it is much more clear? I didn't even think about splitting them like that.

Comment: @ConfusingCalc I'm not quite sure how your class has discussed what you call the **Limit Comparison Test**. In my mind, it is enough of a proof to say "this looks like the sum of $1/n^{3/2}$, so it converges"; I don't know the criteria for what constitutes a proof in your course. Hopefully splitting them up makes convergence clear, though...

Comment: Your method is fine. Just extra work, and some details left out about getting rid of the log part.

Comment: Thanks for the example Benjamin and thank you Andre for the confirmation. I struggled understanding the series in class so I'm trying to learn it, albeit slightly differently from the way the teach taught it. The teacher likely taught it well (and without the extra work that I put up there) but once I missed the foundation for series i fell behind quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{ \dfrac{\sqrt{n} +1}{n^2 + ln(n)}} { \dfrac{1}{ n^{\dfrac{3}{2}}} }
=lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{n^2 + n^{\frac{3}{2}}} {n^2 + ln(n)}=lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1+\dfrac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}}{1+\dfrac{ln(n)}{n}} =1$

So for suffiently large $n$ we have $\dfrac{\sqrt{n} +1}{n^2 + ln(n)}$ is approximately equal $\dfrac{1}{ n^{\frac{3}{2}}} $ . By the comparison test you get the result.

Comment: In a sense, I did it correctly then?